# Comparison about security between file layout and object layout of pNFS

Tags: linux, nfs, nfs4

In the three types of pNFS (block layout, file layout and object layout), as I know, block layout is lack of security. So, between file layout and object layout of pNFS, which type is more secure?

Comment: Please don't keep asking essentially the same question [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/783576/comparison-about-security-between-file-layout-and-object-layout-of-pnfs) and [over](http://serverfault.com/questions/783574/comparison-between-performance-of-block-layout-file-layout-and-object-layout-of) again. The method to draw more attention to a question is to offer [a bounty](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) (although the results of that are not guaranteed).